# Singular points of analytic continuation

Tags: complex-analysis

In Knopp's theory of functions part 1, the following fact about analytic continuation is mentioned without proof. And I am looking for a simple proof.

Let $$f(z) = a_0 + a_1(z-z_0) + a_2(z-z_0)^2 + \dots$$ be a power series around $z_0$ with radius of convergence $R$ where $0 < R < \infty.$

Let $z_1$ be a point in the region of convergence with $ 0 < |z_1 - z_0| <  R.$

Assume that $f$ can be expanded in a power series around $z_1$ with a radius of convergence exactly equal to $R_1 = R - |z_0 - z_1|$.

Clearly, $C$, the circle with center $z_0$ with radius $R$ and, $C_1$ the circle with its center at $z_1$ with radius $R_1$ intersect at exactly one point, say $z_2$ and $C_1$ lies within $C$. 
Knopp mentions that $z_2$ is a singular point of $f$ in the following sense : given any neighborhood of $z_2$,say $U = B(z_2,r)$, there is no analytic function, $g$ defined on $U$  whose values coincide with the values of $f$ on $U \cap B(z_0,R)$.

My observations :

To prove this, it is sufficient to show that given any $r > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $B(z_1,R_1+\delta) \subseteq B(z_0,R) \bigcup B(z_2,r) \tag{*} \label{e:1}. $

To see this notice that if an analytic function $g$ exists on $B(z_2,r)$ for some $r > 0$, such that the values of g coincide with the values of $f$ on $B(z_0,R) \bigcap B(z_2,r)$  then $g$ is an analytical extension of $f$ on $B(z_0,R) \bigcup B(z_2,r)$ and moreover assuming $\eqref{e:1}$ it means that $f$ can be extended to an analytical function on $B(z_1,R_1+\delta)$. However this means the radius of convergence of the power series determined by $f$ at $z_1$ must be strictly larger than $R_1$ which is a contradiction.

So it remains to prove $\eqref{e:1}$ which is a purely geometric problem. A visual representation suggests that if $\delta$ is chosen to be less than the length of a segment joining $z_1$ and $A$ where $A$ is a point of intersection of the circle at $z_2$ with radius $r$ and $C$ the circle with center at $z_0$ with radius $R$ we should be good. But I don't see an easy proof.

[image: singular point]

Comment: Why should $f$ have a value anywhere on $C?$

Comment: The easy proof notes that $\overline{B(z_1,R_1)}$ is a compact subset of the open set $B(z_0,R) \cup B(z_2,r)$. That doesn't give an explicit $\delta$, but that's not needed.

Comment: @zhw It does not have to. I am just saying existence of $g$ implies the definition of $f$  can be extended to the union of the circles $C$ and $C_2$ in the above figure.

Comment: @DanielFischer You are correct. That works. Can you make it an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest proof, if one knows a little topology, is to note that $\overline{B(z_1,R_1)}$ is a compact subset of the open set
$$U = B(z_0,R) \cup B(z_2,r)\,.$$

The continuous function $z \mapsto \operatorname{dist}(z,\mathbb{C}\setminus U)$ is strictly positive on $\overline{B(z_1,R_1)}$, hence it attains a strictly positive minimum $\eta$ there, and any $\delta \in (0,\eta]$ works.

This does not give an explicit expression for a viable $\delta$, though, unless one works through the geometry (which would make the appeal to compactness superfluous, but is more work).